# Enable compression and caching of SVG files in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, caching, svg, compression

When I analyze my website with Google PageSpeed Insight, I should fix some problems regarding compression of SVG files.

I've been looking all around the web trying to find a solution on this problem, but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work, so therefor I'm now asking you guys.

I've checked if gzip is enabled through multiple tools on the web, and that seem to be true.

So far I got this in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]

AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

## FILE COMPRESSION ##
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|svg|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^image/svg+xml.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
## FILE COMPRESSION ##

# mod_deflate configuration
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Restrict compression to these MIME types
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml+rss
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

I really hope for someone to come up with a solution to my problem since I've tried myself for several hours.

Browser caching doesn't work for SVG neither. Maybe there are a similar problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very late response but was seeking the same myself today.

The correct expires by header line would be:

```
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
```

Likewise the image/svg+xml can be used for the gzip declarations.

Answer (score 11):

Please use these three in .htaccess:

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

################ Expires Control ################
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
```

Definitely will enable compression for svg files on website.

Comment: I also had to add `ExpiresActive on` before the `ExpiresByType ...` to make the cache expiration work. More info: https://htaccessbook.com/useful-htaccess-rules/

Comment: Using @Gurunatha 's method and still no luck, every other file (image file) is cached but .SVG > https://fastload.website/PageSpeed/

Comment: `AddType image/svg+xml .svg` and `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml` necessary on most servers. Thanks @Gurunatha Dogi !

Comment: AddType was crucial here, thanks.